# User with Distribution email address

Tags: email, user

I am trying to create user with distribution email address but Distribution email is not getting any login email details from salesforce

Comment: not in spam folder or auto-screened as spam by your mail system?  SFDC treats a user's email address as just that, an email address. How it is set up on your mail system doesn't matter to SFDC

Comment: It's weird. I have the done the same few months ago, it was working fine. as a matter of fact, the distribution email address has multiple user associated and all the users got the email about login. Did you check by putting a different email Id. Check for Deliverability as well .

Comment: Does your email server allow emails to the distribution list from outside of your organization? We once had this issue where the email server was rejecting Salesforce emails to distribution list as it was blocked as per policy.